# Composition over inheritance in this case?

Tags: c#, inheritance, composition

Wanted to solicit whether composition over inheritance makes sense here, and if so a good way to go about it.

I have an interface like so:

```
public interface IUser
{
  string FirstName {get; set}
  string LastName  {get; set}
}
```

There's an 'advanced' user interface as well, which has the same fields as IUser, but with some extras.  PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, etc.

Should this `IAdvancedUser` interface inherit from `IUser` and add its own properties, or would containing an instance of `IUser` within it, and using setter injection to instantiate that member, make sense as well?  If the latter, are there some .Net/C# idioms that work well under these circumstances-- for instance, exposing the `IUser` members as `IAdvancedUser` ones via wrapping or another approach?

These are DTO objects and won't have methods in them, only properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: Must an `IAdvancedUser` always be an `IUser`?

In that case: No, use inheritance.

However, "`composition over inheritance`" do not apply to interfaces since they doesn't follow                      the same rules as classes.

You could for instance do this:

```
interface IAdvancedFeatures
interface IUser
interface IAdvancedUser : IUser, IAdvancedFeatures
```

In that way you could enable anything to implement the advanced features while not forcing it to be a user, while in other cases everyone must be advanced users.

I usually try to treat interfaces as defining features instead of roles. So you could say that you should favor composition (like my `IAdvancedUser`), but not in the same sense as for classes (where you compose internally).